# If S is an arbitrary set and T is a non-empty subset of S, show that there exists a surjective function g which maps S onto T.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

Full question:If S is an arbitrary set and T is a non-empty subset of S, show that there exists a surjective function g which maps S onto T by constructing such a function. What is the rule for the function (it should show what output corresponds to what input)?
I've been stuck at this question for some time. My problem is that nothing is known about the set S except that it is non empty. I have no idea what the solution should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just consider mapping every member of $S \cap T$ to itself, and arbitrarily choose an element of $T$ for the value of the function at every other value of $s \in S \setminus T$. This is like a "partial" identity function.

If $S \neq T$, then this function won't be injective. But it will always be surjective, so long as $T$ is a subset of $S$.